# Cannot seem to find what is wrong

Tags: java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Salaries
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
   {
      String filename = args[0];
      Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(filename));


      int sum = 0;

      in.nextLine();

      while(in.hasNextLine())
      {
        int totalSalary = 0; 

        String line = in.nextLine();
        String[] lineArray = in.nextLine().split("\\s+");

        for(int i = 0; i <= lineArray[i].length(); i++)
        {
            String arrayInts = lineArray[i];

            if(lineArray[i].contains("$"))
                {


                  arrayInts = arrayInts.replace("$","");
                  arrayInts = arrayInts.replace(",","");
                  totalSalary = Integer.parseInt(arrayInts);
                  sum = sum + totalSalary;
                }  
         }        

       }
      System.out.printf("$%,d\n",sum);
      sum = 0;




    }
}
```

I can not figure out why I keep getting an out of bounds error. My code is supposed to go through a text file and gather the numbers and create totals.

Text File Below:

```
Campus President Salary Housing Auto Allowance
Bakersfield Horace Mitchell $285,000 $50,000 $12,000
Channel Island Richard R. Rush $275,000 $60,000 $12,000
Chico Paul J. Zingg $279,500 $50,000 $12,000
Dominguez Hills Mildred Garcia $295,000 provided $12,000
East Bay Mohammad H. Qayoumi $276,055 $60,000 $12,000
Fresno John Welty $299,000 provided $12,000
Fullerton Milton A. Gordon $295,000 provided $12,000
Humboldt Rollin C. Richmond $297,870 $50,000 $12,000
Long Beach F. King Alexander $320,329 provided $12,000
Los Angeles James Rosser $325,000 $60,000 $12,000
Maritime William B. Eisenhardt $258,680 provided $12,000
Monterey Bay Diane F. Harrison $270,315 provided $12,000
Northridge Jolene Koester $295,000 provided $12,000
Pomona J. Michael Ortiz $292,000 provided $12,000
Sacramento Alexander Gonzalez $295,000 $60,000 $12,000
San Bernardino Albert K. Karnig $290,000 $50,000 $12,000
San Diego Stephen L. Weber $299,435 provided $12,000
San Francisco Robert A. Corrigan $298,749 $60,000 $12,000
San Jose Don W. Kassing $328,209 provided $12,000
San Luis Obispo Jeffrey D. Armstrong $350,000 $60,000 $12,000
San Marcos Karen S. Haynes $270,568 $60,000 $12,000
Sonoma Ruben Arminaña $291,179 $60,000 $12,000
Stanislaus Hamid Shirvani $270,000 $50,000 $12,000
```

Comment: please tell us the error message and the line where it happens

Comment: Where did you get an out of bounds error? Stack trace pls...

Comment: `String line = in.nextLine(); String[] lineArray = in.nextLine().split("\\s+");` are you'r sure that's correct? you are jumping two lines at this point. replace the second `in.nextLine()` with `line`. so if the linenumber in your file is even... it will crash (even instead of odd because one line is skipped before the loop starts)

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
 at Salaries.main(Salaries.java:27)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you are getting your out-of-bounds on this line of code:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= lineArray[i].length(); i++)
```

(I shouldn't be guessing here; the details of what's going wrong should have been in your original post.)

First, you probably want to be testing against `lineArray.length`, not `lineArray[i].length()` (which is the length of a specific `String` element of `lineArray`). Second, you should be using `i < ...` rather than `i <= ...`. The actual length of an array is not a legal index into the array.

So change that line to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < lineArray.length; i++)
```

Comment: Thanks so much I knew it was a boneheaded mistake!

Comment: ah you are right. my solution will fix his next question if he fixed the actual problem